# How to use Normal Variable inside Static Method

Tags: php

```
class Exam {
  public $foo = 1;
  public static function increaseFoo(){
    $this->foo++;
    echo $this->foo;
  }
}

Exam::increaseFoo();
```

This code generate an Error

```
E_ERROR : type 1 -- Using $this when not in object context -- at line 5
```

Is that possible to use global variable into static mathod?

Comment: I HAVE ADDED THE COMMENT REGARDING THIS  WHAT YOU ASKED. SORRY YOU CAN'T DO THAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `$this` with `self`, also you must mark your variable as static when using it in a static method:

```
class Exam {
  public static $foo = 1;
  public static function increaseFoo(){
    self::$foo++;
    echo self::$foo;
  }
}

Exam::increaseFoo();
```

Comment: `Line : 5,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC)`

Comment: @ARNAB sorry, I update answer - add $ before your variable name

Comment: `E_ERROR : type 1 -- Access to undeclared static property: Exam::$foo -- at line 5`

Comment: Yes I know that ... but my question is ... without using static keyword before the variable may I use this variable in the Static method ?

Comment: @ARNAB you can use static vars only in a static methods

Answer (score 0):

Variable inside class has to be static. No need to declare the variable as public.

```
class Exam {
  private static $foo = 1;
  public static function increaseFoo(){
      self::$foo++;
      echo self::$foo;
  }
}

Exam::increaseFoo();
```

Comment: without using static keyword before the variable may I use this variable in the Static method ?

Comment: No, the php interpreter would throw an error.
The self keyword refers to the current class. In other words, use $this->member for non-static members, use self::$member for static member. For encapsulation I would also declare the variable as private.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Variable needs to be static as the method where you want to use this variable is static method

Secondly, need to use self:: instead of $this-> while refferencing the class